# Debugging and changing an enum value

Tags: ida, windbg

I'm training reverse engineering and I'm creating some codes in C++ in other to reverse and see what I can do to learn.

I've compiled this code:

```
#include <iostream>

enum Types
{
    One,
    Two
} type;

void helloWorld()
{
    if (not type == Two)
      std::cout << "Sorry, you coundl't do that." << std::endl;
    else
      std::cout << "Yeah, you rocks!" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    type = One;
    helloWorld();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it's a really simple code, just for learning. What I want to know is: How can I change the "type" of the `enum` value.

I'm using Windows 64bit, the only debuggers I have here is WinDbg and Visual DuxDebugger and IDA as disassembler.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change the enum value"? Change one specific check? Change the set of values so new values are used in the whole program? Provide an example of what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember all enum operations are encoded as operations with integers.
So,

`if not type == two`

will be encoded as

```
  008c0:    8b 05 ae 08 20 00       mov    0x2008ae(%rip),%eax        # 601174 <type>
  4008c6:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  4008c8:   75 07                   jne    4008d1 <_Z10helloWorldv+0x15>
  4008ca:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  4008cf:   eb 05                   jmp    4008d6 <_Z10helloWorldv+0x1a>
  4008d1:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4008d6:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  4008d8:   74 1e                   je     4008f8 <_Z10helloWorldv+0x3c>
  4008da:   be 34 0a 40 00          mov    $0x400a34,%esi
```

(g++, Linux, x64)

To fix this check you'll need to perform one of the following alternatives:

- Patch the jump instruction which corresponds to this specific check
- Patch the comparison

There is no possibility to change enum values in the whole program because the information about this specific enum type is lost during compilation.

By the way your "one" enum value will be encoded as 0, and "two" as 1.
If you want to have enum values corresponding to the words, you'll have to define the enum as follows:

```
enum Types
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
} type;
```